# Не работает детальный просмотр элемента Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Есть инфоблок, он же каталог. Когда нажимаю "подробнее" вместо детальной страницы элемента открывается общая страница с каталогом.
Настройки ЧПУ инфоблока:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В компоненте поддержка ЧПУ включена, вот настройки ссылок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что интересно, если вызвать с главной страницу 404.php, то та же картина - открывается страница с каталогом.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Проверьте заполнены ли у разделов и элементов поля "Символьный код"

Comment: @Nikolaj Sarry заполнен